# Draw texture to FrameBufferObject using specific color

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx, blending

I have a texture and I want to draw it to a FrameBufferObject. The texture has transparent areas. I would like the following:

1. For all transparent pixels, let them be drawn transparent in the FrameBufferObject.
2. For all non-transparent pixels, let them be drawn using a color of my choosing, ie pure red (ignore their actual rgb value)

I've tried `Batch.setColor(red)` before drawing the texture, but that just tints it - I want all non-transparent pixels to be drawn pure red.

I am also trying to figure out how to achieve this in just opengl directly, looks like there may be a way to do this with blending, which can then be related back to gdx.

Thanks

Comment: Not quite sure but look into glBlendFunc and glBlendColor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a shader and the shader is the OpenGL program that renders the texture. So your shader would render transparency without change and all else would the color of your own choosing.

The following link has libgdx shaders for palette swapping i.e. direct reassignment of color at render, which you can easily adapt for single color and transparency.

https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/12241616.html